# Min Max component, objective function

Tags: openmdao

I would like to perform some optimizations by minimizing the maximum of a specific path variable within Dymos. or the maximum of the absolute of such a variable.

In linear programming methods, this can be done by introducing slack variables.

Do you know if this has been attempted before with Dymos, or if there was a reason not to include it?

I understand gradient based methods are not entirely suitable for these problems, though I think some "functions" can be introduced to mitigate this.

For example,
The space shuttle reentry problem from [Betts][1] used as a [test example][2] in dymos, the original source contains an example where the maximum heat flux is minimized. Such functionality could be implemented with the "loc" argument as:

phase.add_objective('q_c', loc='max')

[1]: J. Betts. Practical Methods for Optimal Control and Estimation Using Nonlinear Programming. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, second edition, 2010. URL: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9780898718577, arXiv:https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9780898718577, doi:10.1137/1.9780898718577.
[2]: https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/examples/reentry/reentry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done with pseudospectral methods before. Dymos currently doesn't have any direct way of implementing this, for a few reasons:

1. As you said, doing this naively can introduce discontinuous gradients that confuse the optimizer. When the node at which the maximum occurs switches, this tends to cause a sharp edge discontinuity in the gradient.
2. Since the pseudospectral methods are discrete, you cannot guarantee that the maximum will occur at a node. It's often fine to assume it does, but sometimes your requirements might demand more precision.

There are two possible ways to get around this.

1. The [KSComp in OpenMDAO](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/ks_comp.html) can be used as a "differentiable maximum".  Add one after the trajectory, feed it the timeseries data for the output of interest, and set it up such that it returns a smooth approximation to the maximum.  The KS function is a bit conservative, so it won't pick out the precise maximum, but depending on the value of the `rho` option it can be tuned to get pretty close.
2. When a more precise value of a maximum is needed, it's pretty common to set up a trajectory such that a phase ends when the maximum or minimum is reached.

If the variable whose maximum is being sought is a state, this can be done by adding a boundary constraint on the rate source for that state.
This ensures that the maximum occurs at the first or last node in the phase (depending on if its an initial or final boundary constraint).  That lets you more accurately capture its value.

If the variable being sought is not a state, its possible to use the polynomials that are used for fitting states and controls in a phase to interpolate the variable of interest.  By then taking the time derivative of that polynomial we can get a reasonably good approximation for its rate. The master branch of dymos has a method `add_timeseries_rate_output` that does this. And soon, within a few weeks hopefully, we'll add `add_boundary_rate_constraint` so that these interpolated rates can be easily used as boundary constraints.

In the meantime, you should be able to achieve this by adding the timeseries rate output and then manually applying the OpenMDAO method 'add_constraint' to the resulting timeseries output, using either `indices=[0]` or `indices=[-1]` to treat it as an initial or final constraint.

This is a common enough request that we'll add some documentation on how to achieve this behavior using both the KSComp approach and the boundary constraint approach.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear. I was exactly refering to the Kreisselmeier-Steinhauser Function, didnt realize it was already in OM, and just realised it is indeed possible with the phase break.

Comment: As a follow up on option number 1. If understand correctly, the KSComp would require in that case, as the "width" argument, the number of nodes (num_nodes). For example in the "Single-Phase Space Shuttle Reentry" Dymos example, knowing a priorir transcription of 120 nodes, one would add p.model.add_subsystem('ks', om.KSComp(width=120,  add_constraint=True)). p.model.connect('traj.reentry.timeseries.q','ks.g'). pase0.add_objective('q', ref=70 ). Wouldnt this crash if the transcription changes? (eg. by simulation). Should the KSComp be defined inside the ODE instead?

Comment: Simulation is only evaluating the ODE for each phase it simulates, so the KSComp won't come into play during simulation.  simulate doesn't do any optimization, it's strictly for verifying that the pseudospectral result is close to an explicitly integrated trajectory.

In this case it might be useful to define the transcription before the phase, and then pass the total number of nodes to the KSComp's instantiation:


```
tx = dm.Radau(num_segments=20, order=9, compressed=False)

num_nodes = tx.grid_data.subset_num_nodes['all']
```

Comment: I suppose it might be worthwhile to allow aggregation of path constraints and objectives in dymos for this purpose, rather than forcing someone to add a KSComp external to their trajectory.  If that's something you feel would be worthwhile we can add it to the backlog.  Then your original idea of `loc='max'` would result in the Kreisselmeier-Steinhauser function being run on the objective quantity's timeseries.  Although I might suggest we label it 'ksmax' to help users know that it's not a naive maximum.

Comment: If it is possible to add such functionality I think it could be useful for the user, as at least some problems I encounter require to minimize such objectives, as the max. heat flux, max. aerodynamic loads, max of control rates, (and the KS function is a good choice for it even though its conservaitve).  Not sure if it would be much more additional work, but would it be useful to also allow a KS option for related path constraints (for example, max heat flux in the reentry problem) (maybe it reduces number of constraints/comp. time?)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I understand the simulation aspect, though the issue is that when activating grid refinements, the iteration crashes as the transcription changes in the loop (and the KSComp does not update its width). Maybe its possible to just put it inside the phase? (as in a group, with the num_nodes option)

Comment: Ah that's a good insight, yes the entire model would need to have knowledge of that width updated.  I'll have to think about that.  I think for more advanced cases like these, we might have to make provisions for the grid refinement to set  data like width so that its available during setup.

Comment: Hello @RobFalck, has this "ksmax" feature been implemented Dymos or any additional documentation created to show how this type of min max objective can be implemented? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've actually just submitted a pull request to OpenMDAO that implement's it using jax.  Once that's in the main repo you'll be able to utilize it in a component for dymos.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not as much of a fan of KSComp because I've had trouble getting problems getting those types of objectives to converge in the past. I've used the slack variable and that has worked well. In the following example, we take a guess at the Rotor power in static analysis, and then we run a trajectory and get the actual rotor power during the mission. The objective was to minimize aircraft weight, so if you have a large amount of power in statics, that costs more weight. The constraint shown below prevents us from decreasing our updated guess of rotor power in statics below the maximum power required during the trajectory.

```
p.model.add_subsystem(
       'static_power_check', 
       om.ExecComp('Power_check = Power_ODE - Power_statics',
                   Power_check = {'value':np.ones(nn_timeseries_main_tx), 'units':'kW'},
                   Power_ODE = {'value':np.ones(nn_timeseries_main_tx), 'units':'kW'},
                   Power_statics = {'value':0.0, 'units':'kW'}),
       promotes_inputs=[
               ('Power_ODE','hop0.main_phase.timeseries.Power_R'), ('Power_statics','Power_{rotor,slack}')],
       promotes_outputs=['Power_check'])
p.model.add_constraint('Power_check', upper=0, ref=1)
```

The constraint on the slack variable effectively helped us ensure that our slack rotor power matched the maximum rotor power during the mission. This allowed us to get the right sizes for the rotor parts (i.e. motors).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about trying something like this as also having some issues with the KScomp. Will post here if it works

Comment: @GuillermoDominguezCalabuig Hello, have you had any success in implementing the min max objective function?